# Sharepoint Oauth URL returns 404

Tags: 2013, oauth

One of the steps in doing the sharepoint OAuth flow redirects me to

```
https://accounts.accesscontrol.windows.net/metadata/json/1?realm=https://<mysite>.sharepoint.com
```

I have 2 queries regarding this

1) Is this the correct URL? I am not sure what should go in realm  (Also tried entering the client id in realm, no luck)

2) If this is correct, why is it returning a 404 error?

Answer (score 0):

try this url
(please note realm is your tenant id)
https://login.microsoftonline.com/realm/v2.0/token

please search sharepoint oauth 2 to look for what to send to the url as it is a post method